# Where can de-identified Electronic Health/ Medical Record (EHR/EMR) datasets be acquired?

Tags: data-request, medical

Looking for sources of available de-identified EHR/EMR datasets that would be suitable as a benchmark to compare against existing datasets.

This would be similar to what is available from QResearch: https://www.qresearch.org

This is for a US-based project though, so US sources would be ideal.

Answer (score 2):

First check out https://healthdata.gov/.  The US government has a lot of targeted data sets that may be exactly what you need or at least get you started.

As far as accessing "non-gov" data, I've been implementing EHRs for a decade and  I've yet to see organizations make that available other than through an HIE. There are a lot of regulations in the industry and security tends to be very tight.

That being said, I do have a couple of ideas that may help. If you were able to volunteer at a healthcare organization as an analyst (e.g. Volunteers in Medicine) you'd be able to get access to their data.

Moreover, if your research will help a hospital or large medical group solve a pressing problem, data access may not be an issue and they'd  be willing to help you out.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. healthdata.gov looks to be a great resource. Yes, indeed, this question is in relation to a project within a healthcare system.

Answer (score 0):

[Physionet](https://physionet.org/about/database/) is an online repository of EHR databases.

For example, here are some (credentialed access) deidentified ICU datasets:

| Dataset | Location | N hospitals | Source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MIMIC-III | US | 1 | https://physionet.org/content/mimiciii/1.4/ |
| MIMIV-IV | US | 1 | https://physionet.org/content/mimiciv/1.0/ |
| eICU | US | >200 | https://physionet.org/content/eicu-crd/2.0/ |
| HiRID | Switzerland | 1 | https://physionet.org/content/hirid/1.1.1/ |
| AmsterdamUMCDB | Amsterdam | 1 | https://amsterdammedicaldatascience.nl/#amsterdamumcdb |

Comment: https://rdrr.io/cran/ricu/man/data_env.html